# Can I share files/data through App Groups but in different developer accounts applications?

Tags: ios, appgroups

As per my knowledge, I know we can share files between two apps through `App Groups` developed by the same developer account/certificate.

But here my question is : Can I do the same thing `Sharing file between different apps through App Groups` with different apps developed by different developer accounts which handles by my own?

Comment: i highly doubt it.

Comment: Hii Sunil .My requirement also same like you.In my iOS Device am having 2 apps like Demo 1 and Demo 2 .i can share the data between 2 apps. Example i will get  data from Demo 1 through Demo 2  .(Demo 1=>Demo2 ). Case 1 : Demo 1 is using different bundle id from one develper account .Demo 2 is using  different bundle id from another develper account . Is it possible in iOS ?

Comment: @chandrika, Not possible through App Group if apps are from diff. developer account, but you can achieve this by passing parameters(as a data) from Demo1 to Demo2 via [Custom URL Scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Comment: Thanks for your Great answer sunil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is no.

If you create a provisioning profile with an app group `my.app.group` and extract entitlements from it, you will see that the group is referenced as `XXXXXXX.my.app.group` where `XXXXXXX` is your developer ID, so on another account the group will be `YYYYYYY.my.app.group` and it will be perceived as a different group by any device.

More info: [App ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AppID.html), [Application Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW21)

Comment: Great answer! Also can you please put here any apple documentation link if available? But still I agreed, So accepting you answer. thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Apple recently launched **[Files - iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/installerjs/files)** app, Which may help to do this job.

This is little more steps to share/exchange data between 2 different apps from different developer account but it can be work.